# Moles of chlorine gas needed to make up an equivalent amount of saturated salt solution

Tags: concentration, mole, density

I’m trying to solve a question about a saturated salt solution but am unsure of how to answer one of the parts or what it’s asking for.

### The Problem

The maximum solubility of table salt (NaCl) in water at 25 degrees Celsius is approximately 359 g/L. Assume the volume of the solution does not change with the addition of salt.

a) What is the molar concentration of the mixture in mol/L?

b) What is the molal concentration of the mixture in mol/kg? Assume that the density of water is 980 kg/m<sup>3</sup>.

c) How many moles of Cl<sub>2</sub> gas would need to be present in order to make up an equivalent amount of saturated salt solution?

d) What is the density of the mixture?

### My Attempt

a) molar concentration

359 g NaCl * 1 mol NaCl / 58.44 g NaCl = 6.14 mol => **6.14 mol/L**

b) molal concentration

(1 L H<sub>2</sub>O * 1 m<sup>3</sup> H<sub>2</sub>O * 980 kg) / (1000 L H<sub>2</sub>O * 1 m<sup>3</sup>) = 6.14 mol / 0.980 kg = **6.26 mol/kg**

c) moles of Cl<sub>2</sub> gas

I thought it was asking how many moles of chlorine gas is equivalent to the amount of salt in the 1 L solution (359 g NaCl). There are 70.9 g in 1 mole of Cl<sub>2</sub>, so that gives me an answer of **5.06 mol Cl<sub>2</sub> gas** (359 g NaCl / 70.9 g Cl<sub>2</sub>).

But the answer key states the correct solution as ***3.07 mol Cl<sub>2</sub> gas***. How should I go about this part?

d) density of the mixture

density of water = 980 kg/m<sup>3</sup>

density of salt = 359 g/L => 359 kg/m<sup>3</sup>

density of mixture = (980 + 359) kg/m<sup>3</sup> = **1339 kg/m<sup>3</sup>**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a) molar concentration**

There are indeed 6.14 moles of $\ce{NaCl}$ in 359 grams of $\ce{NaCl}$.

I'd prefer to write the molar mass as "$\pu{58.44 g mol^-1 }\ \ce{NaCl}$" or "$\pu{58.44 g/mol}\ \ce{NaCl}$" to keep it all together.

**b) molal concentration**

You got the right value, but you did it the wrong way. For the solvent:

$$\dfrac{\pu{980 kg/m^3}}{\pu{1000 L/m^3}} = \pu{0.980 kg/L}$$

**c) moles of $\ce{Cl2}$ gas**

The book is correct. There are 6.14 moles of $\ce{NaCl}$. Each molecule of chlorine gas contains two atoms of chlorine, so you need half as many moles to get the same number of atoms of Cl. So 6.14/2 = 3.07

*This part of the question has poor phrasing. You can't dissolve 3.07 moles of $\ce{Cl2}$ in water and get a solution of $\ce{NaCl}$.*

**d) density of the mixture**

Your answer is correct.